# Null Pointer Exception in combining two Bitmap Images

Tags: android

I am using a method to `combine two Bitmap Images` and write in the `SDCard`. The App. works fine in the emulator, but when I tried to execute in on the Real Device it throughs `Null Pointer Exception` at this line `cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);` that is to create a `new Bitmap` on which I will draw both the images that are to be combined using `Canvas`.

Now, here in `combineImages(Bitmap background, Bitmap foreground)` the first argument is the `Bitmap from Camera` Picture and the `second is the forefround Gallery item`. The Bitmap taken from Camera is a `static Bitmap`, I guess that is the only thing that is running me into trouble. So, could someone give me a nice solution to save a picture taken from `Camera` as a `temporary` storage so that I doesn't make any issue which using it further.

```
public void combineImages(Bitmap background, Bitmap foreground) { 

        Bitmap cs = null;
        int width = 0, height = 0;
        width = background.getWidth();
        height = background.getHeight();
        cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);
        comboImage.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
        comboImage.drawBitmap(foreground, 100, 300, null);

        String tmpImg = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png";
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + tmpImg);
            cs.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is my Logcat Output when I tried on Real Device.(LG Optimus Black P-970)

```
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:469)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at com.cam.GalleryImageSelected.combineImages(GalleryImageSelected.java:66)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at com.cam.GalleryImageSelected$1.onClick(GalleryImageSelected.java:90)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:874)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:294)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3387)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2408)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
10-04 12:36:08.329: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16356):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Well can I know the reason for a down-vote?

Comment: Are you sure the width and height in the line cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); are greater than 0. Just can't seem to think of another error in that line.

Comment: Yes, because the height and width comes from the picture taken by camera so obviously they are greater than 0. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the problem might be the size of the Bitmap that you are generating by taking a picture from the Camera. So, better try using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` method.

```
width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, width, height, true);
```

This will scale your image according to the height-width of the device height-width. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, It worked the problem was the size of the image was exceeding the size of the device height width...

Answer (score 4):

You basically can't get a Null Pointer Exception at the line you indicated, assuming that [Bitmap](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/graphics/Bitmap.java.htm) is correctly implemented:

```
cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

createBitmap is static.
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 is static.
width, height are ints.

What could possibly be null? Could you post the stack trace of the exception? Are you sure about the line?

Comment: Please checkout my Logcat output, I am getting error at line 66 which is what I indicated.

Comment: Seems like an implementation error in Bitmap API class. Others have experienced the same error:
https://github.com/guardianproject/SecureSmartCam/issues/73
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=613835
It might be a memory issue: when invoking the native bitmap create, there is not enough memory, bitmap is not created and null is returned. The Bitmap class doesn't check if returned bitmap is null, and tries to set some parameters. Try a smaller image, or try freeing up memory before calling the method.

Comment: I guess there might be some solution to it for sure. :(

Comment: All createBitmap() methods rely on the native implementation to allocate memory. If the createNative method is unable to create a bitmap, then i can't imagine a workaround.
You could reuse your bitmap objects, for example use background or foreground to make the combination.

Comment: You can also try to call Bitmap.recycle() when you no longer use your bitmap. This way native allocations are freed up.